# verificar quantidade de caracter php

Tags: php

Como posso verificar se uma string tem mais de 3 caracter?

Tipo Assim:

```
if ($string >= 3) {
   echo "ok";
} else {
   echo "erro";
}
```

Comment: vlw muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Para contar o número de caracateres no php use a função [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) retorna o número de bytes que por conhecidencia pode retornar o mesmo número de caracteres.

Trecho retirado da documentação:

> strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

```
$str = 'NÃO';

echo 'strlen: '. strlen($str) .'<br>';
echo 'mb_ strlen: '. mb_strlen($str);
```

Saída:

```
strlen: 4
mb_ strlen: 3
```

Comment: vlw muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Use o `strlen()`:

```
$string = "Teste de Contador";
$contString = strlen($string);

if ($contString > 3) {
   echo "Tem mais de 3 Caracteres";
} else {
   echo "Essa string tem $contString caracteres.";
}
```

Comment: vlw muito obrigado.